# How to convert MetaStock format to CSV?

Tags: stocks, stock, stockquotes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaStock

Anybody knows how to convert metastock data format to ASCII/CSV format ?

Any sample code (c++/c#) would be of great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command line tool "atem" is a portable open source metastock parser implementaion in C/C++. It's very fast.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/atem

Comment: Thank you Rudimeier, this was what i was looking for. Thanks for mentioning about ms2asc by Mohammed Illyas Mansoor in the Readme. I too had done some googling on ms2asc but in vain.

Comment: How can I do visa versa? @rudimeier

Answer (score 1):

Metalib is a non-free .NET API for reading and writing Metastock files:

http://www.trading-tools.com/metalib.htm